# Number of parameters sent via URL in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to find how many parameters sent in an URL.

How can I determine the number of parameters sent via URL in nodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use req.query

if Your URL is like `localhost:3000?param1=&param2=`

```
var params = req.query;
van length = Object.keys(params).length;
```

the length is 2.

Comment: is that same for an url like this : `https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=y6hEAAAAYAAJ&q=jules+verne&dq=jules+verne&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y`

Answer (score 2):

**If using express framework**

```
req.params // can be used
```

[See the documentation here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params)